# How can I make my UITableView more fluid?

Tags: ios, uitableview

When I run my UITableView, it jumps whenever it has to load a new cell. I recoded each cell so instead of up to 13 subviews, it contained just a couple, and the contents is drawn in drawrect. Its a lot smoother than it was, but is nothing in comparison to the buttery tableviews that a lot of apps have, including messages and path, which both perform a lot of custom drawing for each cell. It still lags, even with a lot of the code blocked out.

How can I make it less jumpy, what is usually the cause of this?

Comment: Are you sure you are dequeueing reusable cells correctly?

Comment: It would be good if you could add some code to support your question..

Comment: @Andrew What do you mean by you think you are and may not too???

Comment: I'm at Uni ATM, will post code when I get home. @R.A I think Im doing it right, but maybe there's something I'm doing wrong that I'm not aware of. I was asked if I was 'sure'. I'm mot absolutely certain I'm doing it right, but Im quite confident I am.

Comment: Lets see then what you done in your code after you posted it..

Comment: +1 for the use of the term "buttery".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Instruments to find where the CPU time is spent. Afterwards try to optimize your code based on that gained knowledge.